# How do I set more than one y-axis coordinate on one chart in HighCharts?

Tags: highcharts

UPDATE AGAIN - Now I added yAxis property but it's showing nothing:

```
$('#highchart').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'My Data'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'By Day'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: date_arr
    },
    yAxis: [{title: {text: 'PV'}}, 
            {title: {text: 'UPV'}}, 
            {title: {text: 'PPV'},opposite: true}
    ],
    plotOptions: {
        line: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            enableMouseTracking: true
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'PV',
        data: pv_arr,
        yAxis:1
    },
    {
      name:'UPV',
      data:upv_arr,
      yAxis:2
    },
    {
      name:'PPV',
      data:ppv_arr,
      yAxis:3
    }
    ]
});
```

It will show nothing - literally nothing, not even the title of the chart. But a blank area.

UPDATE - Now I am using this but still not working...

```
$('#highchart').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'My Data'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'By Day'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: date_arr
    },
    yAxis: [{title: {text: 'PV'}}, 
            {title: {text: 'UPV'}}, 
            {title: {text: 'PPV'},opposite: true}
    ],
    plotOptions: {
        line: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            enableMouseTracking: true
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'PV',
        data: pv_arr
    },
    {
      name:'UPV',
      data:upv_arr
    },
    {
      name:'PPV',
      data:ppv_arr
    }
    ]
});
```

It's like this (the new labels are ready but the metric is still in the old way):

[image]

-- original post --

I am using HighCharts to show some data for a website visitors

[image]

In this picture above. the Blue and Dark Blue lines are very big because they are page visits. And the Green one is the Page Views/Unique Page Views. That is a very small number comparing to the visit number. How can I set up a second y-axis system as Microsoft Excel can do?

BTW, the dates on the x-axis is too crowded, is there anyway to make them stay in one line automatically? (sometimes there are only 7 days data)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define array of yAxis and then set index of axis in each serie.

```
    yAxis: [{ 
        title: {
            text: 'yAxis 1',
        },
    }, { 
        title: {
            text: 'yAxis 2',
        },
        opposite: true
    }],
```

Example: 
- http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes

You can also disable [align ticks](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.alignTicks) by option alignTicks.

```
chart: {
        alignTicks: false
},
```

Comment: Thanks but still not working good. Would you please take a look at my updates?

Comment: I should add a `yAxis:1`, `yAxis:2`, `yAxis:3` in the `series` section. but still not working, this time it's not showing anything... Please check my updates, thanks!

Comment: oh, finally figured out. should be 0, 1, 2. Not 1, 2, 3. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

refer this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/4b33pvc2/) ,It has three yAxis to show three stacked series

for label relted issues ,you can use tickInterval to show date after an interval

```
xAxis: {

  tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000// One day (change here whatever you prefer)
 }
```

If your labels collapsed with each other you can use staggerLines property in xAxis to show alternate label one step down.

Comment: but they are on different graphs. can we make them on the same one? (need to save the room). I know excel can do this.